# Hide Group header in Grouped ListView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm displaying a GroupedList view, and have both enabled the group header and jumplist. I've tried to hide the Group header, but so far with no luck. This property I want to hide is GroupDisplayBinding. If I don't set it, a default of ToString for my Item is displayed. I just want it gone, as a regular list only with the jump option enabled.

A little update: I searched some samples and what I want is a TableView with and indexed list as displayed here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_2_-_populating_a_table_with_data/#Adding_an_Index

Best regards

Comment: Are you defining this UI via XAML or code?

Comment: xaml most of the time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms listview allows you to specify your own layout for the listview group via `GroupHeaderTemplate` property. You can use this layout to keep the header content empty.

Have a look at [Customizing Listview Grouping](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance/#Customizing_Grouping)

If you want to define the group header layout in code you will have to create a new subclass of `ViewCell` and build the layout. See an example at [Enhancing Xamarin.Forms ListView with Grouping Headers](http://motzcod.es/post/94643411707/enhancing-xamarinforms-listview-with-grouping#_=_)

Comment: yes I can make it empty, but not hide it as I want to. Still not sure ListView is the correct control, see my updated question

Comment: @RasmusChristensen: Did you check the second link? You can set the HeightRequest to make the header very small or hide it. Or you can set heigh in Xaml too.

Comment: Thanks. After a couple of attempts I found the missing HasUnevenRows="True". Of course it also applied to the header rows.