# How to disable grouping on already grouped ListView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, xamarin.forms

I have a ListView which is in `grouped` format.

For plain `ListView`:-

```
Public Class ShortItems
{
  public string ItemName {get;set;}
  public string ItemLocation {get;set;}
  public string ItemDescription {get;set;}
  public string ItemIcon {get;set;} 
}
```

For grouped `ListView`:-

```
Public Class ShortItemGroup: List<ShortItems>
{
  public string HeaderTitle {get;set;}
  
  public ShortItemsGroup(string title)
  {
    HeaderTitle = title;
  }
}
```

My `ListView` is properly displayed in grouped format. The criteria to group is `location`

What I am trying to do is to ungroup an already grouped `ListView`.

I have a button that gives the user choice about how he wants the list to be displayed grouped or plain.

By default the `ListView` style is grouped, if the user wants to change that, he can click on the button and `ListView` should display in plain or ungrouped format.

Any idea how can this be done?

Comment: I would suggest using two different LIstViews, and toggling their IsVisible properties to display only one at a time

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693661/199364) do what you want?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve -  do you suggest that the header can be an empty string? like mentioned in the answer? but then, it will also require me to handle the height of the header. Is there no other better way to achieve this?

Comment: I've never tried to do this, so I don't know. What happens if you set ListView's `IsGroupingEnabled ` to False?